# Why does python 2.7.9 unittest discovery run some tests twice?

Tags: python, python-unittest

In python 2.7.9 when a test module inherits from a test class in another module, the test discovery ends up running some tests twice. Is this a bug or is there a legitimate reason to run some tests twice?

```
$ cat foo/test_foo.py
import unittest

class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    pass

class TestFoo(BaseTestCase):
    def test_A(self):
        pass

class TestBar(TestFoo):
    pass

$ cat foo/test_baz.py
import unittest
from test_foo import TestFoo

class TestBaz(TestFoo):
    pass

$ python -m unittest discover  --start-directory foo -v
test_A (test_foo.TestBar) ... ok
test_A (test_foo.TestFoo) ... ok
test_A (test_baz.TestBaz) ... ok
test_A (test_foo.TestFoo) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Comment: That's intended. The test methods exists in both classes and so they are run twice. Just imagine both classes have a different setup method.

Comment: `from test_foo import TestFoo` causes `TestFoo` to be found in both `test_foo` and `test_bar`.